# Connecting to Heroku Postgres from Auth0 results in: err no pg_hba.conf entry for host, no encryption

Tags: postgresql, auth0, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to connect to my PostgreSQL database hosted on Heroku through Auth0's Database Connections.

I am getting an error when I try to invoke the *Get User* script within Auth0's database actions:

> no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xx.xxx.xx.x", user "xxx", database "xxx", no encryption

The script looks like this:

```js
function loginByEmail(email, callback) {
  const postgres = require('pg');
  const conString = configuration.DATABASE_URL;

  postgres.connect(conString, function (err, client, done) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    const query = 'SELECT id, nickname, email FROM organizations WHERE email = $1';
    client.query(query, [email], function (err, result) {
      done(); // Close the connection to the database
      if (err || result.rows.length === 0) return callback(err);
      const user = result.rows[0];
      return callback(null, {
        user_id: user.id,
        nickname: user.nickname,
        email: user.email
      });
    });
  });

}
```

Connection String:

```
configuration.DATABASE_URL: 'postgres://xxx:xxx@xxx?sslmode=require'
```

I appended `sslmode=require` to the end of my connection string to ensure I have a SSL connection to my database.

I have also tried changing `sslmode=require` to `ssl=true`, which results in a different error:

> self signed certificate

I am unsure where to go from here, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first establish the `client` and specify the `rejectUnauthorized` flag, like so:

```js
const client = new postgres.Client({
  connectionString: conString,
  ssl: { sslmode: 'require', rejectUnauthorized: false }
});
```

Then, instead of using your `postgres` to connect, use the client:

```js
client.connect();
client.query(...);
```

This should solve your problem, and the connection will be encrypted. You won't, however, be protected against **Man-In-The-Middle (MITM)** attacks, as specified in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html).

> [image]

Comment: Should I be adding this to my postgres.connect call so its: postgres.connect(conString, {ssl: {sslmode: 'require', rejectUnauthorized: false}}, function (err, client, done){}?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation, let me know if it worked :)

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem! I am now running into a new error with Auth0 saying cb.apply is not a function. I believe this might be on Auth0s end with a dependency version mismatch. Ill be sure to add an answer to my question of the fully working script once everything is working properly :).

Answer (score 1):

@Pexers solution worked for me, however, somehow it shows TypeScript error. The way I did it is just `ssl: true`:

```js
const client = new postgres.Client({
  connectionString: conString,
  ssl: true
});
```